# Extract daily maximum and minimum values

Tags: r, date, max, min, temperature

Using a large dataset of daily temperature readings over a month, I am trying to extract the daily maximum and minimum temperatures from 7 different loggers.

The data consists of 24 hour readings (1 temperature recorded every hour) over 31 days for 7 different temperature loggers.

Dataset looks like this:

```
Tort    date    time    ibutton.temp
ABD 01/03/12    00:05:01    28.622
ABD 01/03/12    01:05:01    28.122
ABD 01/03/12    02:05:01    28.122
ABD 01/03/12    03:05:01    28.122
ABD 01/03/12    04:05:01    28.122
ABD 01/03/12    05:05:01    27.622
ABD 01/03/12    06:05:01    27.123
.
.
.
.
.
BCY 01/03/12  00:05:01      27.289
BCY 01/03/12  01:05:01      27.485
```

Is there a function that can extract the maximum and minimum temperature from each day period (ie 24 temperature readings)for the whole month?

Any heads up is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or use `data.table` (if `dat` is the data)

```
  library(data.table)
  setDT(dat)[, list(Max=max(ibutton.temp), Min=min(ibutton.temp)), by=list(Tort, date)]
  #  Tort     date    Max    Min
 #1:  ABD 01/03/12 28.622 27.123
 #2:  BCY 01/03/12 27.485 27.289
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `aggregate` on the first two columns

```
> aggregate(dat$ibutton.temp, dat[1:2], function(x) {
      c(max = max(x), min = min(x)) })
#   Tort     date  x.max  x.min
# 1  ABD 01/03/12 28.622 27.123
# 2  BCY 01/03/12 27.485 27.289
```

Or `summaryBy` from package `doBy`

```
> library(doBy)
> summaryBy(ibutton.temp~Tort+date, dat, FUN = c(max, min))
#   Tort     date ibutton.temp.max ibutton.temp.min
# 1  ABD 01/03/12           28.622           27.123
# 2  BCY 01/03/12           27.485           27.289
```

Where

```
> dat <- read.table(h=T, text = "Tort    date    time    ibutton.temp
  ABD 01/03/12    00:05:01    28.622
  ABD 01/03/12    01:05:01    28.122
  ABD 01/03/12    02:05:01    28.122
  ABD 01/03/12    03:05:01    28.122
  ABD 01/03/12    04:05:01    28.122
  ABD 01/03/12    05:05:01    27.622
  ABD 01/03/12    06:05:01    27.123
  BCY 01/03/12  00:05:01      27.289
  BCY 01/03/12  01:05:01      27.485")
```